# Dashboards: What's more important, upper right part of the screen or the lower left?

Tags: website-design, usability, gui-design, interaction-design

Sort of new to UI design. From intuition it seems that the top-left corner is the "most important" or easiest seen part of the screen and the lower-right is the "least important" or last seen part of the screen. (correct me if I'm wrong). But what about upper-right and lower left? To which corners would you assign higher importance?

Comment: Why?  It is unclear if this a question to solve a problem or a random request for opinion.

Comment: Sorry if it sounded like an request for an opinion, in a way I guess it kind of was (since I am designing based on conjecture and testing my users later), but I was looking for facts/"field experience" too

Comment: @DaryllSantos - there are an awful lot of books and websites that cover this. For starters I would recommend Jakob Nielsen. He's written books covering the topic. see: http://www.nngroup.com/

Comment: We'll also need more information about the screen and application. On a desktop webpage top-left might be most important because that's where your eyes land, leaving bottom right the least important. But in a mobile app especially games, the bottom right might be most important as it's easiest for the thumb to touch, leaving the top left least important as it's out of reach. Context matters here.

Answer (score 2):

Readers of web pages follow [an F pattern](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/) when scanning a webpage. Mostly we are conditioned into thinking where a particular UI element would be. For example, a Sign In/ Sign Up link should be in the upper right corner, rather than lower left, based on where I expect it to be.

UI designers do well to differentiate themselves through doing the unexpected, just not in this way.

Comment: While the link is useful you've not really explicitly answered the question here. Which area of the screen has higher visual importance - top-right or bottom-left? What does the F-Pattern say about these screen positions?